# Django capturing query parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am trying to create a Django Rest Framework view that filters a queryset. The docs seem to be ok, but before that I am a little confused how I will capture the query parameters in the urlconf. So far I have only made simple confs like `/app/<id>/<slug>`etc. How can I capture a url like `/api/model?param1=hello&param2=world` so that I can use request.QUERY_PARAMS in my view, as in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering.html#filtering-against-query-parameters)? I was thinking of capturing the params in regular expressions (something like `../param1=(?P<param1>)`) but it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to catch them in the urlconf. Catch query params right in your view code.

```
def myview(request):
    if 'mygetvar' in request.GET:
        myobjects = MyObjects.objects.filter(somefield=request.GET.get('mygetvar', 'defaultvalue'))
        # do something useful
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict)